# CSP in Firefox 20.0: default-src none

Tags: security, firefox, content-security-policy

I have a problem with Content Security Policy in firefox. This is my basic code:

```
<?php include_once 'corepolicies/csp.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
        <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formTest" method="post" action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="getText"/>
            <input type="submit" value="insert"/>
        </form>
        <div id="inDataForm">
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['getText'])){
                    echo $_POST['getText'];
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <script src="listeners/listener.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a simple code in php to submit some data; and this is my php file where I set my CSP header

```
<?php

$rule = "default-src 'none'; ";

$rule .= "script-src ".
        "http://localhost/CSP/scripts/script.js ".
        "http://localhost/CSP/listeners/listener.js ".
        "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js; ";

$rule .= "style-src http://localhost/CSP/style/style.css;";

foreach (array("X-WebKit-CSP", "X-Content-Security-Policy", "Content-Security-Policy") as $csp){
    header($csp . ": " . $rule);
}

?>
```

When I try to load my web page on Chrome all works fine, as under IE, but when I run it on Firefox, it doesn't apply the CSP properly. It says that my scripts and my styles violate the CSP script-src='none' and style-src='none'. So it doesn't see any rule about script-src and style-src and I don't know why.

Can anyone help me please? I'm using Firefox 20.0

Comment: I'm no php person, but i'm guessing your header looks like this:

    default-src 'none'; script-src http:...; style-src http:...;

What happens if you use "allow 'none'" instead, and only set the X-Content-Security-Policy header?

Firefox was undergoing a transition in that period, and only supported the X-Content-Security-Policy header. The debug messages were sometimes misleading.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I tried with allow 'none', but I still have the problem.

Comment: Also, CSP doesn't resolve down to the individual files, just hosts and paths for newer browsers. So my guess is that it was that there was also a message saying the values for script/style-src were invalid, defaulting back to none.

Comment: Yes, something similar, but in other browsers like chrome, opera or IE, there was no problem. Firefox said me that he couldn't verify the files that I put in the rules, so he saw only the default rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.
I tried to make some change to my code and I've found something interesting in the way which Firefox use CSP. Basically it seems the browser can't verify the source of a file (like my JSs or CSS files, or like the jQuery JS file). So he works only with the source domain, like 'self' for my scripts and my style, and http://code.jquery.com for jQuery.
What I've done is to set up a control about the client's user agent and, if is Firefox 22.0 or lower, what I do is use this header:

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' http://code.jquery.com; style-src 'self';
```

And it works fine :)
I was worried about inline scripts, but Firefox disables inline scripts by default when I use the CSP header.

So my code is this one:

```
<?php
function isFirefox(){
    $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $pos = strpos($browser, "Firefox");
    if($pos){
        $pos = strpos($browser, "/", $pos);
        $version = substr($browser, $pos, 4);
        $version = intval($version);
        if($version <= 22) return TRUE;
        else return FALSE;
    }
}

$rule = "default-src 'none'; ";

$rule .= "script-src ".
        "http://localhost/scripts/script.js ".
        "http://localhost/listeners/listener.js ".
        "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js; ";

$rule .= "style-src http://localhost/style/style.css;";

if(isFirefox()){
    $rule = "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' http://code.jquery.com; style-src 'self';";
}

foreach (array("X-WebKit-CSP", "X-Content-Security-Policy", "Content-Security-Policy") as $csp){
    header($csp . ": " . $rule);
}
?>
```

Of course is just a proof, it's not portable or anything else, but if someone has my same problem I think it could help :-)